# ReactJS render function isn't being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I'm attempting to make a chat function using material UI. I created a function where users can post new chat messages which are then sent through the reducer and then saved in the redux store. This process works as intended except for the fact that the new chat message only appears after the user refreshes the page. I'm wondering why my render function isn't being updated. Here's the main chat display.

```
const ChatFunction = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { user } = props;
  const userMessages = props.userMessages || {};
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
    userMessages:
      state.messages &&
      state.messages.find(
        (userMessages) => userMessages.otherUser.username === state.currentMessage
      )
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ChatFunction);
```

The `postMessage` function is then passed through my reducer and my reducer function is called to add the new message to the messages array.

```
export const newMessage = (state, payload) => {
  const { message, sender } = payload;
  return state.map((userMess) => {
    if (userMess.id === message.Id) {
      userMess.messages.push(message);
      userMess.latestMessageText = message.text;
      return userMess;
    } else {
      return userMess;
    }
  });
};
```

So, does anyone know why this isn't refreshing properly?

Comment: Can you confirm that the reducer is returning the correct new array of objects ? I do see an issue here where you mutate the useMess.messages and push instead of spreading. But that shouldn't technically matter cos your `.map` will return a new object array.

Comment: The reducer returns the new array with the new message inside. One strange thing is that this was working the other day but now it no longer works. I thought there might've been a problem with the client-side code that I wrote but now I'm wondering if it's a problem with the server. I only ever made changes to the client-side so I don't see why it would stop working.

Comment: what about the condition in `mapStateToProps` on the `ChatFunction` component ? Are they getting filtered out there? I noticed the condition `state.userMessagess.find(
        (userMessages) => userMessages.otherUser.username === state.currentMessage
      )` which looks suspicisos going by the names so pls verify if this is in order.

Comment: I renamed some of the variables so it's easier to understand but my tests show that it's returning the correct values.

Comment: Did you try logging the `props` within `ChatFunction` and see if you get the actual refreshed data? Cos when you say its returning the correct values, where is it returning correct values from? reducer or mapStateToProps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the user's `messages` array when you directly push into it and mutate other properties.

```
export const newMessage = (state, payload) => {
  const { message, sender } = payload;
  return state.map((userMess) => {
    if (userMess.id === message.Id) {
      userMess.messages.push(message); // <-- mutation!!
      userMess.latestMessageText = message.text; // <-- mutation!!
      return userMess;
    } else {
      return userMess;
    }
  });
};
```

When updating state in react you need to shallow copy state and any nested state being updated into new object references to React's reconciliation works.

```
export const newMessage = (state, payload) => {
  const { message, sender } = payload;

  return state.map((userMess) => { // <-- shallow copy of state
    if (userMess.id === message.Id) {
      return { // <-- return new user message object
        ...userMess, // <-- shallow copy of previous user message object
        messages: [message.text, ...userMess.messages], // prepend message, return new array
        latestMessageText: message.text, // update property
      };
    } else {
      return userMess;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This seems to work but I was adding the new value to the beginning of the array. I usually use ```unshift()``` to add it to the beginning but it seems ```unshift()``` is now causing me problems elsewhere.

Comment: @JoshSusa I see, the `push` adds it to the end of the array. I'll update my answer to add it to the front (i.e. prepend). `unshift` will have the same issue as `push`, mutating the array.